# Count the number of employees for supervisor

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT 
e.lname AS employee_name
, s.lname AS supervisor_name
, e.superssn AS supervisor_ssn
FROM employee e INNER JOIN employee s
WHERE e.superssn=s.ssn
```

I actually have two questions. The first one is, the above statement works just fine. However right now it will show bunch of employees with their supervisor. Not well organized. By the way there are three supervisors. Is there a way to show let's say supervisor A with employees A and supervisor B with employees B and so on?

The second problem is that I also tried to just count the number of employees for each supervisor rather than showing their name with COUNT(), I tried several different ones but non worked.

Comment: The first part can be solved using `ORDER BY s.lname, e.lname` or similar. For your second query you want to show 1 row for each supervisor, with the count of how many employees they supervise?

Comment: For each one it is different. One is three, one is two. And just like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things

1) It is good practice to keep your join predicate with your join.  So change:

```
FROM employee e INNER JOIN employee s WHERE e.superssn = s.ssn
```

To:

```
FROM employee e INNER JOIN employee s ON e.superssn = s.ssn
```

2) To keep them together by supervisor, just use an `order by`:

```
SELECT 
  e.lname AS employee_name
  , s.lname AS supervisor_name
  , e.superssn AS supervisor_ssn
FROM employee e INNER JOIN employee s ON e.superssn = s.ssn
ORDER BY s.lname
```

3) To do a count of employees for each supervisor use a `group by` and the `COUNT` aggregate function

```
SELECT 
  s.lname AS supervisor_name,
  COUNT(*) AS employee_count
FROM employee e INNER JOIN employee s ON e.superssn = s.ssn
GROUP BY s.lname
ORDER BY s.lname
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. For the second question COUNT though, it gives syntax error for some reason. I corrected lanme when I pasted it, but still the same thing.

Comment: I forgot the comma in my answer.  That might be it -- I just changed it now

Comment: Oh yes, that was it. I am appreciated.